# How do i make a fragment class displays in a viewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i have this fragment class.There the output is shown in a listview so we can slide it up and down to view the output. But i want to slide it horizontally instead of vertically to view the output. I came to know that to do that we should use viewPager. How i can apply it to my following code

Myfragmentclass

```
public class NewsDetailFragment extends Fragment {

private View view1;

    private ArrayList<BaseElement> newsdetail;
    private LazyAdapter adapter;
    private Activity activity;
    private CommonVariable commonVariable;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsdetail_fragment, container,
                false);

        activity = this.getActivity();


        commonVariable = (CommonVariable) activity.getApplication();

        view1 = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(NewsDetailFragment.this.getActivity());
        dialog.setMessage("Loading News");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        new BackGround().execute();

        return view;
    }



public class BackGround extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            newsdetail = JSONServices.getNewsDescription();

            return null;

        } 

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
        /* check again */
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            commonVariable.setTheater(newsdetail);

            adapter = new LazyAdapter(newsdetail, activity,Element.NEWS_DETAIL.getType());

            ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) view1).setAdapter(adapter);

            dialog.dismiss();

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    dialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

    }
}
```

Layout_fragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

         <ListView
              android:id="@+id/list"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="match_parent">
         </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go in this link:
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

it has a full sample app.